# XMLSerialize Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, xml-serialization

I am serializing a class and I get the following exception:

> You must implement a default accessor on System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection because it inherits from ICollection.

when the following line is executed:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomConfiguration));
```

Any help?

```
public class CustomConfiguration : ConfigurationObjectBase 
{ 

         public CustomConfiguration () { //DO NOTHING. } 

         [User] 
         public uint Version 
         { get { return ((uint)(this["Version"])); } 
           set { this["Version"] = value; } 
}

}
```

*ConfigurationObjectBase* is derived from *System.configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase*.

Comment: Can you show any version of your `CustomConfiguration` class (in particular the inheritance etc)?

Comment: public class CustomConfiguration : ConfigurationObjectBase
    {
        public CustomConfiguration ()
        {
            //DO NOTHING.
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Version
        /// </summary>
        [User]
        public uint Version
        {
            get
            {
                return ((uint)(this["Version"]));
            }
            set
            {
                this["Version"] = value;
            }
        }
}

ConfigurationObjectBase is derived from System.configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to Serialize this anyway? Seems slightly odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"default accessor" is the special property that returns an object of the collection based on
its index. for example:

```
[Serializable()]
public class IntList : ICollection {

    // Default Accessor Implementation
    public int this[int index] {
        get {

            return 0;
        }
        set { /* Do Nothing */ }
    }
}
```

Therefore unavailable to implement that in existing third-party class. Using xml serializing for ApplicationSettings is very bad idea, use Save(), Reload() and Reset() methods, or use your own not derived from ApplicationSettingsBase CustomConfiguration classes.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have a default constructor, that is, one that does not take any parameters, like so....

```
class foo
{
    public foo() {}
}
```

if the class you are trying to serialize does not have one, XMLSerializer throws that exception.  If you are trying to serialize a built-in class, you are going to have to derive your own or create a wrapper class.

Comment: Note the type is `System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection`... not easy to edit that.