# Anyone know of a good LinkedDictionary/Hashed LinkedList?

Tags: c#, dictionary, linked-list, linkedhashmap, generic-collections

I am in need of a Generic collection that is somewhere in between a Dictionary and LinkedList. I want to be able to:

- Access elements by key
- Access previous and next elements

I've taken a look at the provided Generic collections as well as the specialized collections. I haven't really found what I'm looking for, the closest collections were OrderedDictionary and SortedDictionary.

A quick Google found the following potential collections:

- LinkedDictionary - http://www.glennslayden.com/code/c-sharp/linked-dictionary
- C5 collection (supports Hashed linked lists) - https://github.com/sestoft/C5/

Each seems like it could be a good fit. However, I wanted to ask the gurus at SO what their suggestions would be.

So gurus, what are your suggestions? Have you used these collections or other collections to accomplish these or related goals? Is there something blatantly obvious that I should be looking at and am just missing?

Comment: Why won't you just try either of your suggestions and see?  Without more on what your particular needs are (performance, memory efficiency, licensing, and so on), it would be hard for us to choose.

Comment: @PeterO. Thanks for your comment. I'm definitely planning on it. The reason I asked is simple: I'm a big proponent of the "Do it right the first time" mentality. I wanted to know if there was a better way to do it, before I'd had it done :)

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with things like "C# .NET:". It makes the title hard to read, and the tags do a better job of characterizing your question.

Comment: @JohnSaunders sounds good. I'll not prefix any longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you found your own answer; C5 is good library and has what you are looking for, it has great documentation and tests. Oh, and it's available via [Nuget](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/C5).

Comment: It is? I've never needed to use it before. It's good to have some feedback. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own.  Comments & constructive criticism welcome.

```
/// <summary>
/// A LinkedDictionary is a hybrid of a LinkedList and a Dictionary.
/// The LinkedDictionary can be traversed in four ways:
/// 1. Enumerated using .GetEnumerator() - which doesn't guarantee key order
/// 2. Indexed using .ElementAt() - risky, as the underlying dictionary doesn't guarantee order integrity
/// 3. Looked up by key like a regular Dictionary - slow due to hashing and binary-tree search overhead https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1
/// 4. NEW WAY: crawled using .Next() or .Previous() - guarantees sequential order if values are added in key-sequential order
/// IT IS LINKED: Each node can be traversed back and forwards using Previous() and Next() like a LinkedList
/// IT IS OPTIONALLY SEQUENTIAL: if this flag is set, new values can only be added to at the end of the dictionary (keys are compared) to ensure index-sequence is preserved.
/// Partial inspiration from http://www.glennslayden.com/code/c-sharp/linked-dictionary
/// </summary>
public class LinkedDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : Dictionary<TKey, LinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue>>,
        ILinkedDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    where TKey : IComparable
{
    #region Members

    ICollection<TKey> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Keys => base.Keys;
    ICollection<TValue> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values => base.Values.Select(v => v.NodeValue).ToList();

    public new TValue this[TKey index]
    {
        // kludge for serialization error "InvalidOperationException: You must implement a default accessor because SerializableDictionary inherits from ICollection"
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331755/xmlserialize-exception
        // TODO: check this works!
        get
        {
            if (this.ContainsKey(index))
            {
                return base[index].NodeValue;
            }

            return default;
        }
        set => base[index] = new LinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue>(value);
    }


    public bool IsReadOnly => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public bool IsSequential { get; }

    #endregion Members

    #region Constructor

    public LinkedDictionary()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public LinkedDictionary(bool isSequential)
        : base()
    {
        this.IsSequential = isSequential;
    }

    public LinkedDictionary(bool isSequential,
                            SerializationInfo info,
                            StreamingContext  context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        this.IsSequential = isSequential;
    }

    public LinkedDictionary(bool isSequential, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        : base(comparer)
    {
        this.IsSequential = isSequential;
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Methods

    #region Methods - Add
    /// <summary>
    /// Add new entry - check order if IsSequential flag is set
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public new void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (this.IsSequential)
        {
            // new item MUST have a key greater than the previous key; this is the optional Sequential character of this collection
            if (this.Count > 0)
            {
                int comparisonResult = key.CompareTo(base.Keys.Last());
                if (comparisonResult < 1)
                    throw new LoggedException("Cannot add new item.  Key must be greater than the last key.");
            }
        }

        // Create the new Linked entry
        LinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue> newEntry = new LinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue>(value);

        // Link the new value in IF there's something to link it to
        if (base.Values.Count > 0)
        {
            LinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue> existingLastValue = base.Values.Last();

            // Create forwards-looking link from the existing last entry to the new entry
            existingLastValue.Next = newEntry;

            // Create backwards-looking link from new entry to the existing last entry
            newEntry.Previous = existingLastValue;
        }

        base.Add(key, newEntry);
        ;
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        this.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    #endregion Methods - Add

    #region Methods - Get
    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        if (base.TryGetValue(key, out var theNode))
        {
            value = theNode.NodeValue;
            return true;
        }

        value = default(TValue);
        return false;
    }

    public TKey FirstKey() => this.Keys.First();

    public TKey LastKey() => this.Keys.Last();

    public ILinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue> FirstNode() => this.Values.First();

    public ILinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue> LastNode() => this.Values.Last();

    public TValue FirstValue() => this.Values.First().NodeValue;

    public TValue LastValue() => this.Values.Last().NodeValue;

    #endregion Methods - Get

    #region Methods - Remove
    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return base.Remove(item.Key);
    }

    #endregion Methods - Remove

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public new IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return base.GetEnumerator() as IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>;
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion Methods
};


/// <summary>
/// LinkedDictionaryEntry
/// Base type for Values in LinkedDictionary<K, V>
/// </summary>
[DebuggerDisplay("_previous = {Previous} _next = {Next}")]
public class LinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue>
    : ILinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue>
{
    #region Members

    #region Members - Next

    public ILinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue> Next { get; set; }

    public ILinkedDictionaryEntry NextUntyped => this.Next;

    #endregion Members - Next

    #region Members - Previous

    public ILinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue> Previous { get; set; }

    public ILinkedDictionaryEntry PreviousUntyped => this.Previous;

    #endregion Members - Previous

    // VALUE
    public TValue NodeValue { get; }

    #endregion Members

    #region Constructor

    public LinkedDictionaryEntry(TValue nodeValue)
    {
        this.NodeValue = nodeValue;
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Methods

    // Remove this item from a list by patching over it
    public void Unlink()
    {
        this.Previous.Next  = this.Next;
        this.Next.Previous = this.Previous;
        this.Next          = this.Previous = null;
    }

    // Insert this item into a list after the specified element
    public void InsertAfter(LinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue> e)
    {
        e.Next.Previous = this;
        this.Next       = e.Next;
        this.Previous    = e;
        e.Next          = this;
    }


    public void SetNext<TValue>(ILinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue> newEntry)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.NodeValue.ToString();
    }

    #endregion Methods
};


public interface ILinkedDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    TKey     LastKey();
    TKey     FirstKey();
    TValue   FirstValue();
    TValue   LastValue();
    new void Add(TKey key, TValue value);
    string ToString();
}


public interface ILinkedDictionaryEntry
{
    ILinkedDictionaryEntry PreviousUntyped { get; }
    ILinkedDictionaryEntry NextUntyped     { get; }
}

public interface ILinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue>
    : ILinkedDictionaryEntry
{
    ILinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue> Previous { get; set; }
    ILinkedDictionaryEntry<TValue> Next     { get; set; }

    TValue NodeValue { get; }

}
```

Comment: This code has evolved a bit but I'm leaving this copy unchanged to allow comments.

Comment: The LinkedDictionary I wrote has allowed an incredibly difficult problem in time-series analysis to be solved.  The new code runs around 100x faster.  I'm still interested in people's constructive criticism of the concept but as far as I'm concerned it's been very successful.