# Unable to Deserialize XML in C# - Unrecgnized element 'add'

Tags: c#, xml

I have a C# app that uses a custom section for configuration. I have that section of XML defined as a string. The string looks like this:

```
var xml = @"<departments>
  <department id=""1"" name=""Sporting Goods"">
    <products>
      <product name=""Basketball"" price=""9.99"">
        <add key=""Color"" value=""Orange"" />
        <add key=""Brand"" value=""[BrandName]"" />
      </product>
    </products>
  </department>
</departments>";
```

This XML matches the schema defined by the classes I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158503/unable-to-deserialize-xml-in-c-sharp-invalidoperationexception). When I pass the above string to the `Departments.Deserialize` method, I receive an error. The error says: "Unrecognized element 'add'". The debugger jumps to this line in my `Departments` class.

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
  this.DeserializeElement(reader, false);
}
```

I assume that the error is referring to the 'add' elements in the 'product' element. However, the `Product` `ConfigurationElement` has a property named `KeyValueConfigurationCollection Items`. For that reason, it seems that `add` would work.

Why am I getting this error how do I fix my code so that the XML string shown above can be deserialized?

Comment: Can you show us Department and product code?

Comment: @L0uis - The code is in the related SO post I wrote referenced above, which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158503/unable-to-deserialize-xml-in-c-sharp-invalidoperationexception).

Comment: All the attributes need two double quotes instead of one.  You have one string and the double quotes around the attributes are creating errors.

Comment: In my code, the attributes do have two double quotes instead of one. Let me try to fix the snippet. In either case, I'm still getting the error I mentioned.

Comment: I don't think `XmlSerializer` knows anything about the conventions of `System.Configuration`, in this case `<add>` (and `<remove>`). Try adding an `IXmlSerializable` implementation to `Product` and/or `ProductCollection` as you did for `Departments`.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy Unfortunately, that did not work.

Comment: If you know you'll only ever have `<add>` elements, you might try putting `[XmlElement ("add")]` on the inner `KeyValueConfigurationCollection Items` (not tested, file down as needed). If that doesn't work or if it messes up reading from the configuration file, you have two options - either head to reference source and figure it out, or make the contents of your custom section plain XML rather than a bunch of `ConfigurationElement`s, so that `XmlSerializer` knows what to do with them. I'd go with the latter unless there were compelling reasons not to.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy Didn't work. Notably, if I remove the `<add key...` elements from the block, the serialization runs fine. This leads me to believe there's an issue with serializing the `KeyValueConfigurationCollection` typed info. Yet, I'm not sure how to get past it.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy - So, it has something to do with the `IsDefaultCollection` property. If I add a wrapper property named `Items` around the `add` elements it works. However, if I don't have the wrapper element, it doesn't work. It's like `IsDefaultCollection` is not being respsected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update: Long story short - wrong serializer.

Most of the code works, except that particular deserialize method.

I was able to rectify original solution ([here](https://antonymale.co.uk/custom-configuration-sections-in-csharp.html)'s where I found inspiration).

The section that I've corrected and it worked (don't forget IXmlSerializable from original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158503/unable-to-deserialize-xml-in-c-sharp-invalidoperationexception)):

```
private static string sectionName = "departments";

public static Departments Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Departments), new XmlRootAttribute(sectionName));
        Departments departments = null;

        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        departments = (Departments)serializer.Deserialize(xdoc.CreateReader());

        //var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Departments));
        //using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        //{
        //    departments = (Departments)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
        //}

        return departments;
    }
```

---

Hopefully it will help you moving on. At least works on my machine. Let me know if full code listing needed.

### [Keeping original solution, plain reading of suggested problematic xml block]

- Test client.

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = @"<departments>
                          <department id = ""1"" name = ""Sporting Goods"">
                               <products>
                                 <product name=""Basketball"" price=""9.99"">
                                      <add key = ""Color"" value = ""Orange""/>
                                      <add key = ""Brand"" value = ""[BrandName]""/>
                                 </product>
                               </products>
                          </department>
                       </departments>";

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = LoadXmlsFromString(str);

        string productXpath = "descendant-or-self::product";
        var nodes = ExtractNodes(xmlDoc, productXpath);
        foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
        {
            var node = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("descendant-or-self::*")?.OuterXml;
            var obj = Product.Deserialize(node);
        }
    }

    private static XmlNodeList ExtractNodes(XmlDocument xmlDoc, string xpath)
    {
        var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);
        return nodes;
    }

    private static XmlDocument LoadXmlsFromString(string str)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(str);
        return xmlDoc;
    }
}
```

- Reading product is implemented by adding [XmlElement("add")] attribute for the list of add elements (and element-object to convert into).

---

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("add")]
public class KeyValue
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static KeyValue Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        KeyValue keyValue = null;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KeyValue));
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            keyValue = (KeyValue)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
        }
        return keyValue;
    }
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("product")]
public class Product
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("add")]
    public List<KeyValue> KeyValueList { get; set; }

    public static Product Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        Product product = null;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Product));
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            product = (Product)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
        }

        return product;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: I tried this. However, it was unsuccessful for me. As shown in the SO question, the `Product` is deeper in my object hierarchy. For that reason, I can't call `Deserialize` directly. In my scenario, the `Product` is getting properly serialized / deserialized with the exception of the `KeyValueList` property. It's so weird. I don't understand why that's not getting included during serialization / deserialization.

Comment: @zachTempleton, got it, thanks for reply. I was able to find the root cause in original code and was able to introduce a fix (see answer update). Should have used another XmlReader along with XDocument, instead of TextReader. That worked. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion an `XmlSerializer` is not needed for the configurations you have to read. All the tools that `System.Configuration` provides you are more than enough. Here I rewrote your configuration classes (the basic structure):

```
public class DepartmentsConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("departments", IsRequired = false, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public DepartmentItemCollection Departments
    {
        get
        {
            var departments = this["departments"] as DepartmentItemCollection;
            return departments;
        }
        set
        {
            this["departments"] = value;
        }
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(DepartmentItemCollection), AddItemName = "department")]
public class DepartmentItemCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new Department();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((Department)element).Name;
    }
}

public class Department : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("id", IsRequired = false, IsKey = true)]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)(this["id"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["id"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true, DefaultValue = "")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)(this["name"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["name"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("products", IsRequired = false, IsKey = false, IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    public ProductCollection Products
    {
        get
        {
            return (ProductCollection)this["products"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["products"] = value;
        }
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ProductCollection), AddItemName = "product")]
public class ProductCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new Product();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((Product)element).Name;
    }
}

public class Product : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true, DefaultValue = "")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)(this["name"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["name"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("price", IsRequired = false)]
    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return (decimal)(this["price"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["price"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("", IsRequired = false, IsKey = false, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(KeyValueConfigurationCollection), AddItemName = "add")]
    public KeyValueConfigurationCollection Items
    {
        get
        {
            var items = base[""] as KeyValueConfigurationCollection;
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            base[""] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The `<configSections>` in *App.config*:

```
  <configSections>
    <section 
        name="departmentConfiguration" 
        type="Test.DepartmentsConfiguration, Test" 
        allowLocation="true" 
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
    />
  </configSections>
  <departmentConfiguration>
    <departments>
      <department id="1" name="Sporting Goods">
        <products>
          <product name="Basketball" price="9.99">
            <add key="Color" value="Orange" />
            <add key="Brand" value="[BrandName]" />
          </product>
        </products>
      </department>
    </departments>
  </departmentConfiguration>
```

And how to read it using the `ConfigurationManager`:

```
DepartmentsConfiguration config = (DepartmentsConfiguration) ConfigurationManager
    .GetSection("departmentConfiguration");

foreach (Department department in config.Departments)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{department.Id}, {department.Name}");

    foreach (Product product in department.Products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{product.Name}, {product.Price}");

        foreach (string key in product.Items.AllKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{key} -> {product.Items[key].Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

I know it is not consistent with your question, take it as a personal advice.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `System.Xml.Linq`'s **`XDocument`** ?

**Personal Pros:**

- Simple
- No 3rd Party
- Easy to read, for smaller files
- Allows Linq Syntax

**Personal Cons:**

- Tends towards spaghetti code in bigger files
- Not the fastest solution

#### Example

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
var xml =
@"<departments>
<department id=""1"" name=""Sporting Goods"">
<products>
<product name=""Basketball"" price=""9.99"">
<add key=""Color"" value=""Orange"" />
<add key=""Brand"" value=""[BrandName]"" />
</product>
</products>
</department>
</departments>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));

var adds = xDoc.Root.Elements("department")
                    .Elements("products")
                    .Elements("product")
                    .Elements("add")
                    .Select(s => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s.Attribute("key").ToString(), s.Attribute("value").ToString()))
                    .ToList();

foreach (var department in xDoc.Root.Elements("department"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("department: {0}", department.Attribute("name"));
    foreach (var products in department.Elements("products"))
    {
        foreach (var product in products.Elements("product"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("product: {0}", product.Attribute("name"));
            foreach (var config in product.Elements("add"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("add: {0} -> {1}", config.Attribute("key"), config.Attribute("value"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```